# How to fix position of option element BS5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i fix position of the option element ?

As you see when you open the select element , options are not right under the select element they are little bit on left side, how can i fix it ?

Im using Bootstrap 5

```css
select{
  border-radius: 0 !important;
}

select:focus{
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="edit_status">Status</label>
<select id="edit_status" class="form-select" name="edit_status">
  <option value="0">Active</option>
  <option value="1">Disable</option>
  <option value="2">None</option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean that you want the `Status` label to be directly underneath the select text and its options.

The `.form-select` class adds `.75rem` padding on the left to the `select` element.

You could also add this padding left amount to the label.

---

```css
label#edit-status-label {
padding-left: 0.75rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
<script
  src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label id="edit-status-label" for="edit_status">Status</label>
  <select id="edit_status" class="form-select" name="edit_status">
    <option value="0">Status</option>
    <option value="1">Disable</option>
    <option value="2">None</option>
  </select>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```